# R function to paste information from different rows with a common column?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I understand we can use the `dplyr` function `coalesce()` to unite different columns, but is there such function to unite rows?

I am struggling with a confusing incomplete/doubled dataframe with duplicate rows for the same id, but with different columns filled. E.g.

```
id    sex    age    source
12     M      NA     1
12     NA     3      1
13     NA     2      2
13     NA     NA     NA
13     F      2      NA
```

and I am trying to achieve:

```
id    sex    age    source
12     M      3     1
13     F      2     2
```

Comment: This seems like something that should be fixed at the source.... Group by ID and select the first non-NA value.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
library(dplyr)
#Data 
df <- structure(list(id = c(12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L), sex = structure(c(2L, 
NA, NA, NA, 1L), .Label = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"), age = c(NA, 
3L, 2L, NA, 2L), source = c(1L, 1L, 2L, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  fill(everything(), .direction = "down") %>%
  fill(everything(), .direction = "up") %>%
  slice(1)

# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   id [2]
     id sex     age source
  <int> <fct> <int>  <int>
1    12 M         3      1
2    13 F         2      2
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 you can select the first non-NA value in each group. This can be done using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(across(.fns = ~na.omit(.)[1]))

# A tibble: 2 x 4
#     id sex     age source
#  <int> <fct> <int>  <int>
#1    12 M         3      1
#2    13 F         2      2
```

Base R :

```
aggregate(.~id, df, function(x) na.omit(x)[1], na.action = 'na.pass')
```

Or `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) na.omit(x)[1]), id]
```